# Subdomain not mapping to load balancer backend service in Google Cloud Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

I've created a Cloud DNS Zone for `example.com` and pointed it's A record to Load Balancer's Static IP.

In the Load balancer, I have configured `foo.example.com` to point to the `foo-backend-service`:

[image]

When I navigate to `foo.example.com`, it doesn't work.

Do I need to explicitly create an A record entry for `foo.example.com` in the Cloud DNS Zone and point that to the Load Balancer's Static IP.

Answer (score 1):

The domain names `example.com` and `foo.example.com` are different DNS names. Therefore you need to create DNS resource records for each one.

If you plan to keep `example.com` and `foo.example.com` pointing to the same load balancer, use a CNAME mapping `foo.example.com` to `example.com`. Otherwise create an A record with IP addresses pointing to the load balancer.

In your question you are showing your backend rules. Unless you need to specify rules for mapping urls, delete the extra entries and just use the default rule (I cannot see the right hand side so I don't know what you are trying to accomplish). I think you were trying to map `foo.example.com` to `example.com` which is not usually correct in your case.